# navigation bar last item doesn’t float properly

Tags: html, css, list

I was trying to make the nav bar all in the same line but the last block in the nav bar didnt work
html:

```
 <div id="navbar"><ul>
           <li>Home</li>
           <li id="title">Welcome to this website</li>
           <li>Sign up to get update to your inbox:<input type="text" placeholder="Type in your email adress"></input><input type="submit" value="submit"></intput></li>
 </ul></div>
```

css:

```
#navbar li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-size:25px;;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#D2A7F2;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:33%;
    border-right:2px solid #FF2508;
    border-bottom:2px solid #FF2508;
```

}

```
#navbar ul{
        list-style-type:none;
}

#navbar{
       overflow:hidden;
       margin-left:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `box-sizing: border-box;` will fix the issue you have given padding which increases the `width` by adding `box-sizing: border-box;` the `padding` is given from inside

also set `ul` `width` to `100%` if you want to take make it full screen and `li` should be 33.33%

remove the `left`  `-ve margin` for you `#navbar` and add `margin:0` because it will remove default `margin` given by browser

Answer (score 0):

Add box sizing to include the padding and increase the width to equal (closer to) 100%.

```
#navbar li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33.33%
}
```